# Unable to Set-Up unity remote?

Tags: unity, android-studio

I have installed Android Studio and set the path in unity. And I am able to build apks with no problem. But when I try to test in unity remote unity gives an warning as

> Set-up Android SDK path to make Android remote work

I don't know what is happening. If Android SDK path is not set then how am I able build the apks.

I tried to solutions like *enabling usb debugging mode **,** running unity editor first then opening Unity Remote **,** installing Google USB driver component of Android SDK* but none of them worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You set-up the path in external tools unity preferences ?

[image]

Comment: Yes I set up the path in external tools

Comment: I don't think we can build apks without setting it..

Comment: Strange... If everything is right in the path in the external tool, try reinstall the sdk